# SLD Pointsymbolizer with color ramp based on first random attributes

Tags: geoserver, sld

The company I work at does drillings all over the country. These drillings are then presented as a service. So obviously this layer needs an SLD. For the moment every drilling is a green point, but we would like to go a bit more complicated.
The latest idea was to the following:
From a certain scale we'd like to let predetermined colors be filled for every dossier. One dossier can contain multiple drillings, but every drilling has a field which clearly notes that dossier.
I've determined the scale, that's no problem, but I have no clue of how I can add a different color to every dossier grouped point currently in the screen.

Anyone have a clue to how this could be worked out?